# Fail to display data as ListView from Firebase

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase

My goal is just to retrieve data from Firebase and then output it as ListView in Android (No need to push anything back to the database). I tried to learn from the [AndroidChat](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) example and created my own class and my own Custom List Adapter class instead of Chat.java and ChatListAdapter.java (as in the orignal example). I also changed the references to my Firebase and resemble my data structure to that of https://android-chat.firebaseio-demo.com/. Below is my data structure: (Everything below is just the same as the AndroidChat example, just different variable names)

[image]

My own class:

```
package com.firebase.androidchat;


public class MenuItem {

    private String food;
    private String weekDay;

    // Required default constructor for Firebase object mapping
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MenuItem() { }

    MenuItem(String food, String weekDay) {
        this.food = food;
        this.weekDay = weekDay;
    }

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public String getWeekDay() {
        return weekDay;
    }
}
```

My own custom list adapter class:

```
package com.firebase.androidchat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.firebase.client.Query;

public class MenuListAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<MenuItem> {

    public MenuListAdapter(Query ref, Activity activity, int layout) {
        super(ref, MenuItem.class, layout, activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, MenuItem item) {
        // Map a MenuItem object to an entry in our listview
        String weekDay = item.getWeekDay();
        TextView authorText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.author);
        authorText.setText(weekDay + ": ");
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(item.getFood());
    }
}
```

My MainActivity in brief:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // TODO: change this to your own Firebase URL
    private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://barlaurea.firebaseio.com/";

    private Firebase ref;
    private ValueEventListener connectedListener;
    private MenuListAdapter menuListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
        // Setup our Firebase ref
        ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("menu");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Setup our view and list adapter. Ensure it scrolls to the bottom as data changes
        final ListView listView = getListView();
        // Tell our list adapter that we only want 50 messages at a time
        menuListAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(ref.limit(50), this, R.layout.chat_message);
        listView.setAdapter(menuListAdapter);

        menuListAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                listView.setSelection(menuListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
```

When I started the Run button, my device displayed a toast message "Connected to Firebase" but the screen remained blank and then crashed after a few seconds, showing a toast "Unfortunately, Firebase Chat has stopped". What did I miss here? Thank you!

Edit: Here is my LogCat view: Everything turn red at the "FAIL EXCEPTION: main line"
Also the original AndroidChat run fine on my device..

```
02-07 16:17:35.105: D/dalvikvm(31766): GC_CONCURRENT freed 313K, 16% free 7795K/9223K, paused 14ms+16ms, total 65ms
02-07 16:17:36.000: D/dalvikvm(31766): GC_CONCURRENT freed 494K, 17% free 7874K/9479K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 34ms
02-07 16:17:36.365: D/dalvikvm(31766): GC_CONCURRENT freed 482K, 17% free 7923K/9543K, paused 19ms+21ms, total 142ms
02-07 16:17:36.495: D/AndroidRuntime(31766): Shutting down VM
02-07 16:17:36.495: W/dalvikvm(31766): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fb02a0)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766): com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.firebase.androidchat.FirebaseListAdapter$1.onChildAdded(FirebaseListAdapter.java:63)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.firebase.client.core.ChildListenerContainer$1.run(ChildListenerContainer.java:52)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766): Caused by: com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "weekday" (class com.firebase.androidchat.MenuItem), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "weekDay", "food"])
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@42826fc8; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.firebase.androidchat.MenuItem["weekday"])
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
02-07 16:17:36.520: E/AndroidRuntime(31766):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat output when crash occurs?

Comment: Hi @KhawarRaza, thanks for pointing it out, I have attached it to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer has been found here:

[Firebase's AndroidChat example: Failed to bounce to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698441/firebases-androidchat-example-failed-to-bounce-to-type/21709202?noredirect=1#comment32837454_21709202)

In this case I should have typed weekDay not weekday in the firebase instance.