# Firebase's AndroidChat example: Failed to bounce to type

Tags: java, android, firebase

This question is also trying to find out the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626707/fail-to-display-data-as-listview-from-firebase) that I posted several days ago.

The weird thing about the AndroidChat app is when I changed the Chat class properties name to different name. It result in a "Failed to bounce to type" exception. Same thing happened when I changed the name (from author to author2) in my firebase instance. Below are screenshots describing what I'm trying to say. Also there is a LogCat at the end:

When changing from author to author2 in Chat.java:

[image]

OR when changing the same thing in firebase's instance:

[image]

Same error happens:

[image]

LogCat's log:

```
02-11 11:52:11.735: D/dalvikvm(16033): GC_CONCURRENT freed 339K, 12% free 7825K/8839K, paused 17ms+5ms, total 69ms
02-11 11:52:12.835: D/dalvikvm(16033): GC_CONCURRENT freed 462K, 13% free 7869K/9031K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 40ms
02-11 11:52:12.940: D/dalvikvm(16033): GC_CONCURRENT freed 446K, 13% free 7889K/9031K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 34ms
02-11 11:52:13.140: D/AndroidRuntime(16033): Shutting down VM
02-11 11:52:13.140: W/dalvikvm(16033): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c992a0)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033): com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.firebase.androidchat.FirebaseListAdapter$1.onChildAdded(FirebaseListAdapter.java:63)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.firebase.client.core.ChildListenerContainer$1.run(ChildListenerContainer.java:52)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033): Caused by: com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "author" (class com.firebase.androidchat.Chat), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "message"])
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@424dcef8; line: 1, column: 45] (through reference chain: com.firebase.androidchat.Chat["author"])
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
02-11 11:52:13.150: E/AndroidRuntime(16033):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have only changed on chat message, not all of them. When the code attempts to deserialize a message that you haven't changed to author2, it cannot find the author field and throws an exception.

Try either changing all of the messages to author2, or clear out your data and start over with the new field names.

Comment: yah you may be right. I did try changing all of them to author2 but same errors still occur. Heres what I have changed: http://pastebin.com/R1ginNqx

Comment: Try changing getAuthor() to getAuthor2() as well.

Comment: I also try changing activity_main.xml as my app doesnt need to send back anything. I just delete both the editText and sendButton (or one of them) and the app crashes again. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Make sure that you also remove the references to the editText and sendButton from the main activity. It is likely that the app is still trying to set up handler for various actions with those elements but can no longer find them since you're removed them.

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out Greg's answer more, the chat example is reliant on everything being named correctly across the data in the Firebase as well as on the Android client side. Normally, the Firebase looks like this:

```
android-chat
|---> chat
   |---> pushID
      |---> author
      |---> message
```

If you modify the names of the properties in the Chat.java file or you change the name of ANY of the fields via Forge: https://android-chat.firebaseio-demo.com/ it has the potential to cause this error, since the object cannot be properly created because the JSON to object map link is severed (See FirebaseListAdaptor.java line 63 for this mapping). If a single one of the items stored in the Firebase is incorrect, or the Chat Object naming is incorrect, this error will fire.

On a side note, when users want to play around with the data structure of an app, please create a separate test Firebase and develop on that. I'm not sure which Firebase this happened on, but it's always good practice to spin up a Firebase that is separate from anything currently being used by others.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

*Adding to the answers above.*

I was trying to modify the android chat example and I was doing that correctly all the names were correct and as per the forge. Still I was getting the same error.

*Solution:*
**When creating Bean class, include every child in the structure without leaving any entry.**

In my case I was trying to create a bean according to android application's requirement and thus the error.

Example: I just had two getter methods declared for author and message ( Which is wrong. )

```
android-chat
|---> chat
    |---> pushID
        |---> author
        |---> message
        |---> time
        |---> fourthChild
```

Comment: I was getting this error because I did not have a getter for all of the child keys. +1 for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

> you must fallow [Java Bean Conviction](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm)

I was struggling with this error just because I messed the `default constructor`